# What does this mean regarding loops?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

i passed this project in and the grader gave me 50% saying i did not use function for loops. The instructions said use while loops, or does he mean otherwise? here is the code. the project is supposed to count from 10 to 0 then 0 to 10.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int Integer;

printf("Please enter an integer\n");
scanf_s("%d", &Integer);

int count = Integer;
while (count >= 1)
{
    printf("%d\n", count);
    count--;
}

printf("*****\n");


while (count <= Integer)
{
    printf("%d \n", count);
    count++;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: we don't have any idea of what you're taking about, sorry.

Comment: who is we? seems straight forward question.

Comment: then wait for an answer then "i passed this project in and the grader gave me 50%" sorry I'm lost

Comment: `0` is not displayed twice.

Comment: Maybe he means that you should break your program up into functions rather than have everything in the `main` method

Comment: thanks @DavidRawson i think you are right

Comment: @DavidScarpa you are welcome. Good luck with your studies!

Answer (score 1):

This may be related to a specific style the grader wanted your class to learn, or a specific conversation.  I suggest asking, as your grader's response was (clearly) missing some details for you.

Meanwhile, some suggestions of what your grader might have been looking for.

- Did your grader literally mean for you to use `for`-loops?

  ```
  for ( ; count >= 1; count--) {
      printf("%d\n", count);
  }
  ```
- Did you forget to count to `0` the first time?  (The above loop will stop printing at 1, not 0.
- Does your grader want you to functionalize the loop kernels?

  ```
  void countDownLoopKernel ( int value ) {
      printf("%d\n", value);
  }

  ...

  while ( count >= 1 ) {
      countDownLoopKernel( count );
      count--;
  }
  ```

For a functioning program, items 1 and 3 are arbitrary.  They can be crucial when fitting into a larger program's (or company's) style, for readability, for following [DRY principals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), or for refactoring, but for small programs like this, they make no difference.  I suspect your grader is trying to get you to think about alternatives beyond "It works, so it's good enough."

Answer (score 0):

They may have wanted you to use both for and while loops. To count from Integer to 1, try this:

```
for (count = Integer; count >= 1; count--)
    printf("%d\n",count);
```

Also, to count from 1 to Integer, try this:

```
for (count = 1; count <= Integer; count++)
    printf("%d \n");
```

I hope this helps!